# How can I create an exception that checks for int range, number type, and not a char?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to wrap my head around exceptions and the problem I'm running into is that I'm being required to create a program that asks for user input for a number 9-99.  This number must be error-checked using 3 different exceptions.

> e1: number is outside of the range (200)
>
> e2: number is of a data type other than integer (double)
>
> e3: input is another data type other than number (char)

I have tried to create patterns in my if structure to make all three work, however I can't get it to differentiate between e2 and e3.  It will always default to e2.  This is what I have with only two exceptions, but I would greatly appreciate help with figuring out how to implement the third.  Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean tryAgain = true;
  do {
       try {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 9 and 99: ");

            int inInt = input.nextInt();

            if (inInt >= 9 && inInt <= 99){
                System.out.println("Thank you.  Initialization completed.");
                tryAgain = false;
            }
            else if (inInt < 9 || inInt > 99){
                throw new NumberFormatException("Integer is out of range.");
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e1) { // Range check
            System.out.println("* The number you entered is not between 9 and 99.  Try again.");
            System.out.println();
            input.nextLine();
        }
       catch (InputMismatchException e2) { // Something other than a number
            System.out.println("* You did not enter an integer.  Try again.");
            System.out.println();
            input.nextLine();
        }
    } while(tryAgain);
}
```

}

Here is the output I get right now:

> > Please enter an integer between 9 and 99: 
> >     2
> >
> > - The number you entered is not between 9 and 99.  Try again.
> >
> > Please enter an integer between 9 and 99: 
> >     f
> >
> > - You did not enter an integer.  Try again.
> >
> > Please enter an integer between 9 and 99: 
> >     88
> >
> > Thank you.  Initialization completed.

https://www.ideone.com/ZiOpGH

Comment: Is there some reason an error message like 'Sorry, that is not valid.  Please enter an integer between 9 and 99 (inclusive).' isn't adequate?

Comment: It is for homework so that's what the exercise required.  I can only assume it's to further the lesson by figuring out how to completely dissect the input.  *shrug*  Trying the below answer now.

Comment: Why throw then immediately catch the exceptions?  Wouldn't it be better to handle the invalid input in an `else` block, using the same logic you'd use within the `Exception`?

Answer (score 1):

In `catch (InputMismatchException e2)`, test to see if `input.hasNextDouble()` (or `input.hasNextFloat()` ? Not sure which one is more general...) is true. If it is, then you can distinguish between the case 'user entered a double' and 'user entered a non numeric type'

Answer (score 1):

If you've got to detect three circumstances, you need to have three sets of logic.

1. Check if the entered characters are a valid numeric value.
2. Check that the entered number is an integer.
3. Check that the entered number falls between the low and high bounds.

And you pretty much have to check them in that order.

Scanner conveniently has the `hasXXX` methods to see whether the characters about to be read match a given pattern.